# Bounds on integral of length of intersection of segments with an arbitrary small set

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider a cube $C$ with edges of length 1 in $\mathbb{R}^n$, centered in the origin, and consider a set $E$ of measure $\varepsilon$ in the cube. No regularity besides measurability. Now, take a point $x_0$ (let's say, the center) and integrate over the cube the function

$$ f_{x_0} (y)= \mathcal{L}^1 ([x_0 , y] \cap E).$$

My question is: is there a uniform bound from above (and, why not, from below) on $\int_C f_{x_0} (y) dy$? I guess this will depend from the measure of $E$, the shape of the bigger set (so, with a ball it might be different) and the choice of the point $x_0$. Are there some references for this kind of problem? Has it been studied?

EDIT: I think this might involve some rearrangement inequality (something like Steiner symmetrization)